# What high level languages support multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, programming-languages

I'm wondering which languages support (or don't support) native multithreading, and perhaps get some details about the implementation.  Hopefully we can produce a complete overview of this specific functionality.

Comment: This is not a language issue, it is an implementation issue. As the question does not make sense, I propose that it be read with respect to implementations.

Comment: I agree with Marcin that it should be read with respect to implementations.  The reason I asked it this way is that I assumed that most languages shared the ability to parallelize between implementations.  For example, C and C++ have threads regardless of which compiler you use.

Answer (score 7):

[Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_programming_language) has built-in support for [concurrent programming](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/conc_prog.html#3).

Strictly speaking, Erlang processe are greenlets. But the language and virtual machine are designed from the ground up to support concurrency. The language has specific control structures for asynchronous inter-process messaging.

In Python, [greenlet](http://codespeak.net/py/dist/greenlet.html) is a third-party package that provides lightweight threads and channel-based messaging. But it does not bear the comparison with Erlang.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that the list of languages that are higher-level than [Haskell](http://haskell.org/) is pretty short, and it has pretty good support for [concurrency and parallelism](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Concurrency_and_parallelism).

Answer (score 3):

Older versions of C and C++ (namely, C89, C99, C++98, and C++03) have no support at all in the core language, although libraries such as POSIX threads are available for pretty much every platform in common user today.

The newest versions of C and C++, C11 and C++11, do have built-in threading support in the language, but it's an optional feature of C11, so implementations such as single-core embedded systems can choose not to support it while supporting the rest of C11 if they desire.

Comment: That's not true anymore in C++11.

Comment: @MaxBeikirch: Thanks—it was true 5.5 years ago when this answer was first written, though, before C++11 existed :).

Comment: Absolutely :) Now your answer is correct and I can upvote it ;)

Answer (score 3):

With CPython, one has to remember about the [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock). To summarize: only one processor is used, even on multiprocessor machines. There are multiple ways around this, as the comment shows.

Comment: This is not true. There are multiple implementations of Ruby and Python that support true parallel threads: XRuby, Ruby.NET, JRuby, IronRuby, Jython, IronPython, and possibly others.

Comment: Corrected my initial, too generic, statement.

Answer (score 2):

Delphi/FreePascal also has support for threads.

I'll assume, from other answers, that it's only native on the Windows platforms.

Some nice libraries that implement better features on top of the TThread Object:

- [OmniThreadLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/omnithreadlibrary/)
- [BMThread](http://www.mitov.com/html/free_downloads.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Clojure](http://clojure.org/) is an up and coming Lisp-dialect for the JVM that is specifically designed to handle concurrency well.

It features a functional style API, some *very* efficient implementations of various immutable data structures, and agent system (bit like actors in Scala and processes in Erlang). It even has software transactional memory.

All in all, Clojure goes to great lenght to help you write correct multithreaded and concurrent code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the official squeak VM does not support native (OS) threads, but that the Gemstone version does.

(Feel free to edit this if not correct).

Answer (score 1):

You need to define "native" in this context.

Java claims some sort of built-in multithreading, but is just based on coarse grained locking and some library support.  At this moment, it is not more 'native' than C with the POSIX threads.  The next version of C++ (0x) will include a threading library as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know Java and C# support multithreading and that the next version of C++ will support it directly... (The planned implementation is available as part of the boost.org libraries...)

Comment: The C# multithreading API's are stupid. There are three ways to do it, none of which "has it all".

The simple way works, unless you need results back from the thread.

The one getting you results back is way more complicated, and conceptually different (I don't remember the API names now, sorry).

Answer (score 1):

[Boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/thread.html) is great, I'm not sure whether you can say its part of the language though. It depends if you consider the CRT/STL/Boost to be 'part' of C++, or an optional add-on library.

(otherwise practically no language has native threading as they're all a feature of the OS).

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't make sense: whether a particular implementation chooses to implement threads as native threads or green threads has nothing to do with the language, that is an internal implementation detail.

There are Java implementations that use native threads and Java implementations that use green threads.
There are Ruby implementations that use native threads and Ruby implementations that use green threads.
There are Python implementations that use native threads and Python implementations that use green threads.
There are even POSIX Thread implementations that use green threads, e.g. the old LinuxThreads library or the GNU pth library.

And just because an implementation uses native threads doesn't mean that these threads can actually run in parallel; many implementations use a Global Interpreter Lock to ensure only one thread can run at a time. On the other hand, using green threads doesn't mean that they can't run in parallel: the BEAM Erlang VM for example can schedule its green threads (more precisely green processes) across mulitple CPU cores, the same is planned for the Rubinius Ruby VM.

Answer (score 1):

Perl doesn't usefully support native threads.

Yes, there is a Perl threads module, and yes it uses native platform threads in its implementation. The problem is, it isn't very useful in the general case.

When you create a new thread using Perl threads, it copies the entire state of the Perl interpreter. This is very slow and uses lots of RAM. In fact it's probably slower than using fork() on Unix, as the latter uses copy-on-write and Perl threads do not.

---

But in general each language has its own threading model, some are different from others. Python (mostly) uses native platform threads but has a big lock which ensures that only one runs (Python code) at once. This actually has some advantages.

Aren't threads out of fashion these days in favour of processes? (Think Google Chrome, IE8)

Answer (score 1):

I made a multithreading extension for Lua recently, called [Lua Lanes](http://luaforge.net/projects/lanes/). It merges multithreading concepts so naturally to the language, that I would not see 'built in' multithreading being any better.

For the record, Lua's built in co-operative multithreading (coroutines) can often also be used. With or without Lanes.

Lanes has no GIL, and runs code in separate Lua universes per thread. Thus, unless your C libraries would crash, it is immune to the problems associated with thread usage. In fact, the concept is more like processes and message passing, although only one OS process is used.

Comment: Lately, I have switched over to Scala which provides the benefits of Lua (short, scripting-like code) but with type safety (essential for larger code base). Scala's actor model nicely wraps together both co-operative (as in native Lua) and OS thread based multithreading, in one API.

Answer (score 1):

Finally `Go` is here with multi-threading with its own pkg `Goroutine`.
People say it is on the structure of `C-language`.
It is also easy to use and understand .

Answer (score 0):

[Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html) and [Python](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-thread.html) do.  Ruby is working on it, but the threads in Ruby 1.8 are not really threads.

Comment: Could you define what "really threads" are, and in what way, say JRuby's or XRuby's or Ruby.NET's or IronRuby's threads are "not really threads"? All of those Ruby 1.8 implementations implement truly concurrent, parallel, native OS threads without a Global Lock. What more do you want from a thread?

Comment: That's for JRuby, XRuby, or Ruby.net.  That's not the ruby most folks use.